# How can I make elements with html like the attached image?

Tags: reactjs, graph

I want to create a page which has many elements with connectors. now, how can I draw these elements on a page with react?

Is there any package for this purpose?

[image: Graph image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful package for drawing elements and their connectors.

https://reactflow.dev